# Custom SSL doesn't show when using CloudFlare

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, cloudflare

I have an EV certificate from godaddy. It works fine and the green address bar with the name of my company shows up when I use it without cloudflare. However when I change my DNS to cloudflare and turn SSL Strict mode on, the green lock says I have a certificate from cloudflare (it shows a different ssl certificate). I don't know what to do to still show my EV certificate in the address bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EV certificates (the green bar) are only supported on paid business or enterprise subscriptions: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170446-Can-I-use-an-EV-or-OV-SSL-certificate-with-CloudFlare-Business-and-Enterprise-only-

Either you don't have such a subscription, so it doesn't accept your EV certificate, or you do - in which case you should contact their support, since that's what you pay for.